# Setting the cursor for a header in a QTreeWidget via PySide

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, pyside, maya

I'm trying to set the cursor for a QTreeWidget's header for when the user hovers over the header. I have tried setting the header in the class through `self.header().setCursor( my_cursor )`, but so far the cursor isn't changing when I hover my mouse over the header. I've searched through Google to try to track down how to do this, but so far I have found nothing. I have tested with PySide 1.2.0 (in Maya 2015) and 1.2.2.

Am I doing this wrong, or is there a workaround? Here's some example of code:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Tree( QtGui.QTreeWidget ):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Tree, self).__init__(parent = parent)
        self.header().setCursor(QtGui.QCursor( QtCore.Qt.WaitCursor))

widget = Tree()
widget.show()
```

If I set the cursor on the tree widget itself, then the cursor is set as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to reset the header of the tree.

Just set the cursor on the viewport of the existing header:

```
    self.header().viewport().setCursor(QtCore.Qt.WaitCursor)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hacky way, but you could do this by casting `self.header()` into a `QWidget`, since `setCursor()` is a method of `QWidget` class.

```
import sys

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui


class Tree(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Tree, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        QtGui.QWidget(self.header()).setCursor(QtCore.Qt.WaitCursor)


widget = Tree()
widget.show()
```

And you don't really have to cast `QtCore.Qt.WaitCursor` to a `QtGui.QCursor` object.

Hope that was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to kartikg3's answer. This will allow for the full length of the header to be used.

```
import sys

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui


class Tree(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Tree, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        header_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        header_widget.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.WaitCursor))
        header_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        header_layout.addWidget(header_widget)
        self.header().setLayout(header_layout)


widget = Tree()
widget.show()
```

The only problem with either approach so far seems to be that adding the widget will remove the ability to change the size of the columns.